# Is there a way to catch InsecureRequestWarning from python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I know it's possible to disable `InsecureRequestWarning` but I need the opposite, I want to either catch it or make the request abort and throw an exception if this warning is present.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of an insecure SSL (so others can experiment with it).

Comment: At least for these two urls, I'm getting an exception. What's the issue exactly? (url = "https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/"
url2 = "https://self-signed.badssl.com/")

Comment: @Roy2012 http://www.rustoms.com, the issue is that I have a bunch of domain to scrape but don't know if they accept https or http.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it with `warnings.filterwarnings("error")`, which turns warnings into errors so they can be caught with try catch.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had a solution for this in the following code but it doesn't because specifying *verify=False* on the request will unconditionally produce the warning regardless of if the URL has a valid cert or not. Unless there is a way to produce that warning without having to specify *verify=False*, then I believe the answer to the question is simply 'no'.

```
>>> import requests
... import warnings
... try:
...    requests.post("https://self-signed.badssl.com", data={"key": "value"})
... except requests.RequestException as ex:
...    print("See if our RequestException is caused by certification verification...")
...    warnings.filterwarnings("error")
...    try:
...       requests.post("https://self-signed.badssl.com", data={"key": "value"}, verify=False)
...    except requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning as ex:
...       print("Handled InsecureRequestWarning:\n\t{}".format(ex))
...    finally:
...       warnings.resetwarnings()
... 
See if our RequestException is caused by certification verification...
Handled InsecureRequestWarning:
    Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'self-signed.badssl.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```